# monitor outgoing email

Tags: monitor, email, postfix

I have a VPS and recently I found some unusual activity looking at the /var/log/mail.log and so I installed pflogsumm to send a daily report and got this:

### Per-Day Traffic Summary

```
date          received  delivered   deferred    bounced     rejected
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Nov 30 2014         6          6 
Dec  1 2014        36         34         10         13          3 
Dec  2 2014        24         20         11         21          2 
Dec  3 2014        34         13         65         20         16 
Dec  4 2014        15         11         59         18         11
```

So, here's the catch.. What deferred means? also bounced and rejected is related to sent emails? I'm thinking there may be a process sending spam somewhere..

Any ways to see what emails are being sent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deferred can be a status of an mail which is processed by your MTA and means that the mails are queued in your MTA. The mail could not be delivered, but it also is not rejected or bounced. This can happens if your MTA tries to send mails to a server who is not accessible via SMTP. You can display all queued mails with the command:

```
    mailq
```

It also displays the sender and the recipient of the queued mails.
Normally the Mail is re-queued (tried to send again) automatically after a while, but you can also re-queue it manually with the command:

```
    postsuper -r ALL
```

If you want to delete all as deferred queued mails you can use the command:

```
    postsuper -d ALL deferred
```

I hope this was helpful Ulli